# Change template parameters

Tags: margins, indentation, templates

I have this overleaf template:

[Template](https://www.overleaf.com/2663904qjtmvy#/7054120/)

If i have a long chapter name it seems cut
This is the result [image: result]

How can insert a new line?
i tried with \\ and \newline command and i get this:
[image: new line]

Or how i can move to left?

Comment: The template is useless without knowing  what make `\input{structure}`. Please make a MWE with the relevant commands included directly in the preamble.

Comment: Impossible to say for sure, but the fact that `\\ ` and `\newline` have no effect suggest that something like `tcolorbox`'s `\tcbox` command is being used, which generally cannot be broken over multiple lines. You will likely need to modify the template itself....

Comment: you could try using a `\parbox` of an appropriate size for the text.  since it's the chapter title, you will also have to provide an optional "short version", since the boxed text won't be suitable for a toc or running head.

Comment: It might be a hint that that style of layout isn't designed for long chapter titles.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is indeed the case. Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 3):

This looks *a lot* like the [Legrand Orange Book](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book) template but with changed colors. For one thing the box around the chapter title looks similar, second the template also uses a file `structure.tex` for including the relevant code. And third [the same problem popped up on latex-community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=25722). Assuming I am right I'll repeat the relevant parts of the answer I gave on latex-community.org here:

> The template has inefficient and restricting definitions of
>   `\@makechapterhead` (numbered chapters) and `\@makeschapterhead`
>   (unnumbered chapters). Here are improved versions which allow
>   multiline chapter titles:
>
> ```
> \makeatletter
> \tikzset{
>   chaptertitle/.style={
>     line width = 2pt ,
>     rounded corners = 15pt ,
>     draw = ocre ,
>     fill = white ,
>     fill opacity = 0.5 ,
>     text opacity = 1 ,
>     inner sep = 15pt ,
>     text = black,
>     node font = \huge\sffamily\bfseries ,
>     text width = \paperwidth-\Gm@lmargin-20pt ,
>     align = left
>   }
> }
>
> \renewcommand\@makechapterhead[1]{%
>   {%
>     \parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
>     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
>       \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
>         \node at (current page.north west)
>           {
>             \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
>               \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
>                 {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
>               \node[anchor=south west,chaptertitle] at (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm)
>                 {\if@mainmatter\thechapter. \fi#1\strut};
>             \end{tikzpicture}
>           };
>       \end{tikzpicture}
>     \fi
>     \par\vspace*{270\p@}
>   }%
> }
>
> \renewcommand\@makeschapterhead[1]{%
>   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
>     \node at (current page.north west)
>       {
>         \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
>           \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
>             {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
>           \node[anchor=south west,chaptertitle] at (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm)
>             {#1\strut};
>         \end{tikzpicture}
>       };
>   \end{tikzpicture}
>   \par\vspace*{270\p@}
> }
> \makeatother
> ```
>
> Adding this to the preamble and using
>
> ```
> \chapterimage{chapter_head_2.pdf}
> \chapter{Text Chapter so long that it spans two lines. Indeed so long that it
>   spans two lines.}
> ```
>
> gives
>
> [image]
>
> More lines are also possible:
>
> [image]